# Mismatched transmission line at DC

Tags: dc, transmission-line, circuit-theory, reflection

The characteristic impedance equation in transmission line theory is this:

$$Z_0 = \sqrt {\frac{R+j\omega L}{G+j\omega C}}$$

Take the case of a twisted pair transmission line, say the cat6 cable represented in this link . 
[Cat6 cable info](http://www.commscope.com/catalog/enterprise)

Either conductor in the pair is well separated by their insulation and an additional plastic spacer, so G is essentially zero. As for R,L, and C, the link above provides that

- R=8.00 ohms/100meters
- L=0 henries
- C=6nF/100meters

If you let omega  go to zero, Z_0 goes to infinity.  This makes sense if the transmission has no load attached to it, but when a mismatched load is attached things get a little messed up. If you try to calculate the load reflection coefficient,  you'll get "-1" as a result.
$$\lim_{Z_0\to\infty} \frac{Z_L - Z_0}{Z_L+Z_0} = -1$$
This implies that zero voltage will be measured at the load
$$\Gamma_L = \frac {V_L^-}{V_L^+}=-1$$
$$V_L = V_L^+ + V_L^- = V_L^+(1 +\Gamma_L) = 0$$

Now we all now that DC voltage dividers work and that's exactly the circuit that I've explained. If I haven't made any mistakes, could someone tell me the physical significance of this result?

/product_details.aspx?id=33613 "cable info"

Comment: L is not zero!!

Comment: The spec sheet does not list L. Plus L being non-zero doesn't affect the end result  I'm presenting.

Comment: Using  $$V_L=V_L^+(1+\Gamma_L )$$ as a steady state solution entails the driver side of the line is terminated to the characteristic impedance. Wherever along the line you look toward the source you see a driver with a finite voltage thru an infinite impedance: output dead.

Comment: My question then is "Why is the line of infinite impedance? "  

The source will indeed be terminated to the line, some voltage will drop across the source impedance, but the line should act like a resistor spanning between the, say positive pole of the source to the positive pole of the load and also a resistor spanning between the negative poles of the source and load...right?

Comment: Who flagged this as low quality? Low quality means quality of the question, if the OP has something wrong then try to get them to correct it not shut it down. It looks like a great question to me as far as length and content

Comment: Thanks laptop2d. Some people might this question is wacky, but I'm trying to figure out if transmission line theory extends to DC.

Comment: Transmission line theory does not apply at DC.  It only applies when the length of the line is comparable to the signal wavelength.  This is clearly stated in all introductory texts - the question demonstrates a complete lack of research.  Why not rephrase and ask "Does transmission line theory extend to DC ?" if that's what you wanted to know?

Comment: If you would have stopped after your first two sentences,  I would have been grateful for your informative post. Instead you decided to be rude. I chose the wording of my question for a good reason even though it might not appear that way to you. Also, missing what might amount to a paragraph in a textbook is common and really not a big deal. If you need to condemn others for small inadequacies, then do it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This question makes no sense, since there is no reactance at DC.

Do you expect to measure 377 ohms with an open circuited ohmmeter ?

Comment: I do suggest that the line is loaded. There is some impedance spanning the far terminals of the transmission line.

Comment: Your question makes no sense - there no reactance at DC.  You will only measure the load and cable **resistance**. Transmission line theory is related to signal wavelength which has no meaning at DC.  Sorry